# Make a double-tapping button (ideally without ICs or keeping ICs to a minimum) for a small "tiny cell" powered device

Tags: digital-logic, analog, flipflop, low-power, button

Conditions:
small device, extremely space constrained (large caps are a no-go)

Powered by a small battery (something like under 120 mah)

Thus, adding a few more ICs like the 555 or "TimeBlox LTC6992" is not desirable

Currently have:

A normal mechanical button that completes a circuit when pressed, and disconnects on release.

+2v, currents  below 5 mA

Needed:

to execute a second short (200ms +/- 50ms) "pulse" when the button is released , but not instantly (after a delay of 150 +/- ~50 milliseconds, effectively producing a fast double-tap on every press-release cycle)

I realize it could be done using a latch IC like MAX16054 and a XOR and several delays... but, once again, space and power constraints make that suboptimal.

Question: is there a way to achieve the double-tap effect keeping additional ICs to a minimum?

P.S.:
While I do realize that a dedicated double-tapper microcontroller may be a good idea (and am interested to hear which microcontroller would be best to use here), I am curious to learn whether there are other, non-microcontroller clever solutions to this

Comment: Sounds like a job for a little 6-pin mcu

Comment: @ajb any particular suggestions?

Comment: Also, while I realize that chances are mictrocontroller is a very good idea, I am genuinely interested to learn if there are other clever ways to solve this

Comment: @Lee This is the meat and potatoes of a PIC10F20x or PIC10(L)F320/322 devices, which come in SOT-23-6. The (L) variety can run from as low as 1.8 V. Just add a PB switch to one pin and use some other pin to drive whatever you want. Nothing else other than the battery is required. You could probably have it operational in the "1-3 microamp" average region, which is basically the "battery self-leakage current" range. Of course, what you drive with it may add something to the picture.

Comment: what's on gthe terminals of the switch, is one of them power or ground?

Comment: @jonk Thanks! That looks like a fascinating MCU and may fit just right. Any opinion on **CY8C3666AXA-052T**? Stumbled upon mentions of it while googling for PIC10LF320 and it looks suspiciously good with power tolerance down to 0.5v ([claimed?](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/100/PSOC_3_CY8C36-1161131.pdf))

Comment: @Jason one of them is power, yes

Comment: @Lee I've got stacks of those here for purposes not dissimilar to what you want. They are nice little Jack off all trades things. I started out using them as power on reset devices with manual PB and a few specialized functions added. But their uses have grown. Price is cheap, too.

Comment: @jonk "stacks of those lying around"... you mean the CY8C3666AXA-052T one or the PIC10(L)320 one? Because try as I might I can't find CY8C3666AXA-052T in less than "full reel" order quantity, and boy do I not feel like spending 6k on a hobby project :)

Comment: @Lee The 200 series parts and also the 322 devices. (All PIC10 series parts.).I think both in dip8 and sot23.

Comment: A non-microcontroller solution would probably involve a couple SR latches along with a two-transistor monostable multivibrator. I'm sure there are plenty of other ways to do it; that's just the most straightforward. I haven't bothered to actually implement it, though.

Comment: @Felthry A problem with BJTs (and not so much with FETs) is getting long timing. Usually means big capacitors, rather than big resistors, due to recombination current issues. A co-mingled BJT+FET helps a lot and allows a balance towards large resistors and small capacitors. That's where I was mentally heading. But the bottom line is that it will be hard to beat the performance, size and part count, current draw, cost, etc. over a SOT23-6 mcu. The only reason not to use the MCU would be if it were boutique. But Microchip is still making PIC17 parts from three decades back. I trust them.

Comment: @jonk Of course, I'd definitely use a microcontroller. But the asker wanted to know if there were any micro-less ways of doing it.

Comment: @Felthry True. I just didn't have room to add a comment to let you know I realized where you were coming from. I did. So what I wrote was not a complaint. Just another note to add to other ones here.

Comment: Okiedokie, I think it would be fair if I accept @jonk 's answer as "the" answer, but I guess for that it will need to be posted as answer and not comment?

Comment: @Lee You can't accept comments. And I'm not entirely sure, but questions without answers might (some time long later) might be deleted or something. (I don't know the rules here -- memory fades.) I could post it as an answer... but, is there anything useful I could add? It's just a recommendation for a specific part and that's not entirely what I'd call an answer -- just a referral of sorts. I could write something about debouncing the manual switch, or talk about keeping it very low power, etc. Do you know how to do those things already?